# Field Calculator populating a new field with strings based on old field with integers

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, string

I have two fields, one is old, Ftype, one is new, Ftype_name. I would like to have python read the numbers in Ftype and populate Ftype_name with the string.  I used to know how to do this before they ruined ArcMap. I cant figure that back out.

A work around I was trying is cloning the Ftype into Ftype_name then use the `.replace()` to replace 390 with the string "LakePond". I keep getting an error that makes no sense to me; "invalid field", the new field is a text field.

I've tried `!Ftype_name.replace(390,"LakePond")!` and `!Ftype_name.replace("390","LakePond")!` as the number should have been converted to a string when it was brought over from the Ftype field, which is a long type. The image below is the field calculator, the error, and attributes table for the shapefile.

[image]

Comment: The `!` symbols go around the field name, not the entire expression.  i.e. `!Ftype_name!.replace(390,"LakePond")`.  If you want to replace all of the values at once, though, use a dictionary: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239644/64255

Comment: !Ftype_name!.replace(390,"LakePond") is not working. This str( !Ftype_name! ).replace('390',"LakePond") does.

Comment: @mikewatt I've tried that too, I get worse results. In the error it doesn't even list the field name, it always lists a number from that column. The error message i get looks like this "390.replace(390,"LakePond")" I used to code like the way you're suggesting. Doing it like this was the only way i could preserve the field name.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you FelixIP. This syntax makes it work.

```
    str( !Ftype_name! ).replace('390',"LakePond")
```

I don't understand why the above code works. The numbers are already coded as strings. When I replicated the column, the new column is made of strings. When I interact with the table in Pyscriptor, I used the `type()` function on rows of the new column, Pyscriptor returns 'str' indicating that the new values are strings. When the `type()` function is used on the original column 'int' is returned indicating that the original column is filled with integers.

It makes little sense to me why I have to convert the replicated column into strings again. If anyone else knows python syntax to translate the number codes into strings and populate a new column with those strings, without having to replicate the original column first, or why the values need to be converted again; that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I see is explicitly casting a field to a specific Python data type, I don't see any columns getting "cloned."

Comment: @bixb0012, no there isn't any cloning going on in the code. I had to clone the number values into the new column, and am transforming the numbers into strings one by one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No field cloned. It worked on integer

Comment: Please indicate in comments the reason for down votes. Is my use of the word "clone" confusing to non-english speakers? Should I use "replicate" or "duplicate" instead? Everyone seems to think that the code is replicating the values into the new column. I am replicating the column to preserve the original column and then preforming operations on the new column to convert the number codes into strings.